# Using two versions of java in one windows machine

Tags: java

I have two jdk versions installed. jdk 9 64 bit and jdk 8 32 bit. Now I need to run a jar file that runs only using 32 bit jre. But I want to keep both of them. After installing jdk 9 my java version is showing it, hence my path was set to jdk 8.
How to can I manage this? Please answer me in detail, as I am a novice developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly use the `java` in your jdk 8 by noting the path to it, such as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\java.exe`.
Then, use that fully qualified path instead of just plain `java` when you run it from command line:

`java -jar jarfilename.jar`

Or, you can navigate to your java.exe inside your jdk8 folder, open up a command line at that location, and pass in the fully qualified/relative path of your jar in the same command.

Or, you can export your jdk8 java.exe as a java8 alias, and your jdk9 java.exe to be java9 alias, include both in the system PATH variable, and call whichever java you like.

The possibilities are really endless.

Answer (score 1):

Just reference to the JDK that you'd like to use. Eg:

```
/path/to/your/jdk/bin/java -jar <jar-file>.jar
# or Windows
C:\_usr\jdk\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java.exe -jar <jar-file>.jar
```

That should be sufficient. You will have to determine which JDK to use yourself upon running your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you normally run your `jar` file by double-clicking it in Explorer, you'll need to change the way you run it if you want to use a specific version of Java.

If Java 8 was installed in the default location, then you need to open a Command Prompt window in the folder that contains your `jar` file and type:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\java.exe" -jar YourJarFile.jar
```

Note that you need to put quotation marks around the path to the Java executable as it contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

To be safe you might want to make sure a couple environment variables like JAVA_HOME and JAVA_OPTS are set.  You also might want a different classpath (depending on what you are running, if it's not just a jar...)

You might set up a cmd file launcher for each app that sets up it's environment and launches the for you using the full path to the JVM you want and setting the appropriate variables.  This method works for double-clicking from explorer since it doesn't require .cmd parameters to be passed, but it requires a cmd file per project.